# Deep copy of linked list

Tags: c++, deep-copy, doubly-linked-list

I have doubly linked list, m_Terminal1 is the begin of list, and m_Terminal2 is the end of the list. Here is my code

```
CBusLine(const CBusLine & orig){
      m_Terminal1 = new TStop(orig.m_Terminal1 -> m_Name);
      m_Terminal2 = new TStop(orig.m_Terminal1 -> m_Name);
      TStop * tmpx = m_Terminal2;
      TStop * copy = orig.m_Terminal1;
      copy = copy ->m_Next;
      while(copy != NULL){
          TStop * copy_tmp = new TStop(copy->m_Name);
          tmpx -> m_Next = copy_tmp;
          copy_tmp -> m_Prev = tmpx;
          tmpx = copy_tmp;
          copy = copy->m_Next;
      }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, when I want to print out the list, there is only first item.
Here is source file http://pastebin.com/YCKyZ31K . Could somebody help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you just rearranged your `Add()` function to actually just add the data (and not do all of that I/O), then the copy constructor becomes 3 or 4 lines of code.  All you need to do that is call Add() in a loop that goes from the first to last item in the list being passed in.

Comment: you should make "CBusLine & orig" be "const CBusLine & orig".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating two objects that have the same name as the first stop (`m_Terminal1` and `m_Terminal2`) and adding the list of the stops to `m_Terminal2`. Because the variables point to different places in memory (courtesy of the `new` calls), they aren't the same item, and in the end, `m_Terminal2` will have the full list, while `m_Terminal1` will just have the first stop. During this process, you aren't storing the last stop in `m_Terminal2`.

One way to fix this is to only initialize and store the first stop initially, go through and add all of the stops, and store (NOT re-initialize) the last stop.

```
CBusLine(CBusLine & orig){
      m_Terminal1 = new TStop(orig.m_Terminal1 -> m_Name);
      TStop * tmpx = m_Terminal1;
      TStop * copy = orig.m_Terminal1;
      copy = copy ->m_Next;
      while(copy != NULL){
          TStop * copy_tmp = new TStop(copy->m_Name);
          tmpx -> m_Next = copy_tmp;
          copy_tmp -> m_Prev = tmpx;
          tmpx = copy_tmp;
          copy = copy->m_Next;
      m_Terminal2 = tmpx;
}
```

Comment: Yes but at first m_Terminal2 is pointing at the same item as m_Terminal1 `m_Terminal2 = new TStop(orig.m_Terminal1 -> m_Name);` So I don't think I'm adding it after last stop. How could I fix it?

Comment: Ah, ok, so you aren't adding after the last stop (I'll revise my answer). However, `m_Terminal2` is NOT pointing at the same item as `m_Terminal1`. You're creating two different objects (courtesy of the two `new` calls), and adding the list to one of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You should reuse code already written.  You wrote an `Add()` function, so why not use it?

First, fix the Add() function so that it calls another function where the sole purpose is to add a node at the end of the sequence:

```
void CBusLine::Add(istream& is)
{   
    string line;
    while(is.good())
    {
        getline(is, line);
        if(line == "")
            continue;
        AddInternal(line); 
    }
}

void CBusLine::AddInternal(string& line)
{
    TStop * n = new TStop(line);
    if(m_Terminal2 == NULL){
        m_Terminal1 = n;
        m_Terminal2 = n;
    }
    else{
        m_Terminal2 -> m_Next = n;
        n -> m_Prev = m_Terminal2;
        m_Terminal2 = n;
    }
}
```

The reason for breaking up the Add() function is that now, the copy constructor (and assignment operator) become very simple to write.

```
CBusLine(const CBusLine & orig)
{
    TStop *startTerm = orig.m_Terminal1;
    while ( startTerm != orig.m_Terminal2 )
    {
       AddInternal( startTerm->m_name);
       startTerm = startTerm->m_Next;
    }
}
```

Of course, the AddInternal has to work correctly.  I'm assuming that m_Terminal1 and m_Terminal2 are the start and end of the linked list.

Given that AddInternal() works correctly, the copy constructor is a simple loop, going from start to end terminal, and calling AddInternal() with the terminal's string data.  This is much more simpler and makes more sense logically than recreating code you already wrote in the Add() function.

Note that you must also write an assignment operator in addition to the copy constructor.